# How to NSLog to shell console

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I wrote a command line utility. I am printing to system console using: 
In MyApp main.m I print Hello World using NSLog.

```
NSLog("Hello World");
```

In shell script I am doing this:

```
someVar = `pathTo/MyApp`
echo $someVar
```

Above prints Hello world in terminal but echo doesn't seem to printing the same.

How to output that to bash shell console ?

Comment: `NSLog` writes your message with the date, the host name, the process name and the PID. Is that what you're trying to achieve with `echo`?

Comment: Or do you mean that the message gets printed to the terminal but `$someVar` is empty?

Comment: @zneak Message gets printed to terminal but `$someVar` is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSLog` prints to stderr, but the shell backtick syntax only captures stdout. You need to [redirect stderr to stdout](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html):

```
someVar=`pathTo/MyApp 2>&1`
echo $someVar
```

Comment: Thanks. How to modify above if MyApp accepts arguments ? i.e., someVar=`pathTo\MyApp arg1 arg2 2>&1`

Comment: Exactly like you suggested. Don't forget to use forward slashes instead of backward slashes though.

Comment: Thanks. Now the problems I see are - shell script prints folder/file names when I do echo, and doesn't respect new lines.